# Stratified Sampling: Forming fraction map for sampleBy method in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a single column dataframe `newDf` as below:

```
+------------+
|       value|
+------------+
|5TEJU62N58Z4|
|000000000000|
|1J4GW48SX4C3|
|1J4GW68S2XC7|
|1J4GK48K04W1|
```

It have 486 rows. I want to do stratified sampling on this dataframe. For that, I would first need to create a fraction map and then pass it as a argument in the `sampleBy` method. This is what I am trying:

```
val fractions = newDf.distinct.map(x => (x,0.8)).collect().toMap
val sampled_df = newDf.stat.sampleBy("value", fractions, 10L)
```

But it errors out saying this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_1")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
```

I also tried preparing fraction like this:

```
val fractions = newDf.map(_._1).distinct.map(x => (x,0.8)).collectAsMap()
```

But it shows me error stating that

```
Error:(32, 33) value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    val fractions = newDf.map(_._1).distinct.map(x => (x,0.8)).collectAsMap()
```

How can I prepare this fraction map so that I can use it in the below `sampleBy` method and do the sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simple

```
newDf.distinct.as[String].collect.map((_, 0.8)).toMap
```

Comment: yeah, it works! I didn't figure that out earlier really! Thanks a ton!!